# Responsive theme jquery flot does not draw for one of the div

Tags: jquery, angular-ui-bootstrap, flot

jQuery Flot chart does not draw in visible (mobile view) but works well in hidden-xs (desktop) view . But if I put the visible-xs block at top before hidden-xs it renders properly in mobile view but not in desktop(hidden-xs) view.

I tried all options but it only gets rendered in one view. Not sure how to fix it. There are other codes which I have removed so having just a single block is not an option.

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    <div id="demo-container" class="demo-container" >
        <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder" ng-init="displayChart()"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="visible-xs">
    <div id="demo-container" class="demo-container"  ng-init=" displayChart(); ">
        <div id="placeholder" class="demo-placeholder"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two div elements with the id `container`and two with the id `placeholder`. Even if one of the two is hidden, both are on your page. This is invalid HTML and Flot may use the currently invisible container (appearantly it always uses the second div on your page).

To solve this you can remove the duplicate ids and use the classes on the div elements and the jQuery `:visible` filter:

```
$.plot('div.demo-placeholder:visible', data, options);
```

And keep in mind that the visible placeholder div must have a height.